# Geometry nodes Spiral demo

Tags: geometry-nodes, bezier-curves, physics, procedural, mathematics

I've been trying to achieve this result for a long time, but I still couldn't figure out how to do it. There's [this sample image in the Blender manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/introduction.html) that is exactly what I want. Procedural spirals that don't intersect with each other so I don't have to manually draw all of them.

Is there a demo file for this image?
So I could learn from it how it was done.

Thanks. :)

[image: Geometry nodes Spiral]

Comment: quellenform? you are really slow today.... :D

Comment: @Chris Ah, OK, is that up to me? I was also wondering why the mouse pointer seems so sluggish today.

Comment: yep it is, far too complicated for me.... :D

Comment: I wouldn't say it's impossible to do this 100% with Geometry Nodes, but with current resources I see reduced chances without not having at least a significant portion of these curves available as a base. In some form it needs a set of rules or some kind of framework here, because the distribution and expansion can't happen completely randomly (Of course it could, but that would probably look weird). This is, I assume, also the reason why curves were probably drawn here for the essential part. Let's think about it, I'm probably wrong too.

Comment: Does anyone happen to know the author of this work? Maybe he/she can shed some light on the matter.

Comment: Seems hard without at least some iteration.. first thoughts.. bounce a ray around with (previous hit dependent?) constraints on length, and defaults for a miss. Convert to Bezier. I don't imagine that wouldn't make lovely geometric spirals, though..

Comment: Yeah, the author would significantly help here. If the curves need to be drawn, I don't see much use of GN (except for some simple settings as material, curve res, height etc). Sadly there's no indication of who made this on the website.

Comment: Just a thought on this: Reminds me of fractals. May be there is a mathematical way to describe such figures. -> Added _mathematics_ tag.

Comment: Another thought: Superposition of force fields may possibly be an approach as well.

Comment: For info to anyone interested who doesn't know the origin of this craft: This technique is also known as [Paper Quilling](https://www.google.com/search?q=paper+quilling) ...from a time when computers and Blender were not used for everything. ;-)

Answer (score 5):

Nice discussion in comments but, you have missed one thing, look at the number of users:

[image]

Now, it is easy to understand, that this node setup only builds one spiral. Moreover, look at spiral node, it has some inputs that we can spot in the screenshot:

[image]

Knowing that, it is easy to understand that this node group builds one spiral, and then you just duplicate and modify inputs and scale plenty of times manually to create this quilling pattern.

Here is how one spiral may build, I used spiral node and add scaling to them with logarithmic progression to make it more "unfold". Looks like divergence value is doing this in the original setup.

[image]

Now we can add depth, but before doing that I want to make them equal height and thickness, without matter if they scaled or not. So here is why global reference is used. Just set plug the relative scale into Set curve radius.

[image]

Final touch is trim curve by common value, you can see the animated value here:

[image]

I have added weighted normals modifier and you can animate growing sheets:

[image]

You can also output a position of the points, to use it in shader to make this gradient look:

[image]

I'm not quite sure about how to unfold spiral to make it almost linear at the beginning, maybe he has used another method, but overall setup looks clear for me.

Answer (score 1):

Check  [this page](https://studio.blender.org/blog/motion-graphics-for-blender-3/), there is a link to the files and a brief explanation of how it works: it basically illustrates the use of geometry nodes to create a tool.

In this case, a tool to draw spirals, scrolls and ornaments. The main work is done manually.

Comment: OMG they made it manually...

Comment: Yes, it basically illustrates the use of geometry nodes to create a tool. In this case, a tool to draw spirals, scrolls and ornaments. The main work is done manually.